# Using ec2 instace in amazon as a proxy to s3 bucket

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, proxy

I want to use ec2 instance as a proxy to connect to my s3 bucket. Does anybody knows how to do that with "apache"server?

p

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? Is it to add additional security? If you provide more information, you will likely get a better answer. Also, please note that StackOverflow is a site for **programming** questions rather than Systems Administration.

Comment: Yes, it is purely for security reasons>